# Identity of a function with isometric differential

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry

If you have a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $df_{x}$ is an isometry for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ how would you show that the identity $<d^2f_{x}(u,w),df_{x}(v)> + <df_{x}(u), d^2f_{x}(v,w)> = 0$  holds for any $(u,v,w) \in \mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n$ ? $<,>, is, of course, the usual scalar product in euclidean space.

I have limited knowledge in functional analysis, however this question popped up in my differential geometry homework. My professor told me to use the "product rule", but with respect to what? If it´s with respect to $x$ then I´m n a problem because, from what I´ve read, I need to consider that $d^2f_{x}(u,w)$ is a frechet derivative of the function $df:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n)$ which I´ve never encountered before in the course. I´m taking some liberties considering that the course I´m taking is introductory so through what I´ve read I tried to define a function $\phi:\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n)\times \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n)\rightarrow B(\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R})$ with $(f,g)\mapsto <f,g>$ with the image being the space of all billinear forms and $<f,g>$ being the billinear form defined by the scalar product (I assume this definition makes sense, but I know I may be talking nonsense because O my limited knowledge).

Now, this is billinear and because each space is of finite dimensión then it must be continuous. My argument then goes that using the product rule given by https://wj32.org/wp/2013/02/21/differentiation-done-correctly-1-the-derivative/ (Theorem 5.5) I get that the derivative of this is then $<df,g> + <f,dg >$ so taking the pair $<df_{x},df_{x}>$ we get the left side of the expression, but because for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ $<df_{x},df_{x}>=<Id,Id>$ because it is an isometry. I stopped here because I wasn´t sure of the last step and I´m not sure if the differential of the identity function is $0$.

I suppose that my question is if there is an alternative way or if my method/something similar to it can be done?

Answer (score 1):

You have $\langle df_x(u),df_x(v)\rangle =\langle u,v\rangle$. If  you differentiate this expression relatively to $x$, you obtain:

$<d^2f_{x}(u,w),df_{x}(v)> + <df_{x}(u), d^2f_{x}(v,w)> = 0$. Since $x\rightarrow \langle df_x(u),df_x(v)\rangle =\langle u,v\rangle$ is the composition of $x\rightarrow (df_x(u),df_x(v)$ with the scalar product $\mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which is a bilinear map.

Comment: Ok I see, because I'm not doing any explcit derivative w.r.t. $u,v$ I can fix them and deal with simpler functions. But the function $x\rightarrow (df_x(u),df_x(v)$ seems to deal with the same problem because it is also a composition, isn't it? You send a vector $x$ to it´s differential and then send that differential to $\mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^n$ which you can't readily differentiate without talking about the differential of a map that goes to and from $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Comment: $u$ is fixed here, so $df_x(u)\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Yea, but let's consider the map $x\mapsto df_{x}(u)$ If x is considered as a free variable then what we get is a function from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ Which can be differentiated normaly, but I still need to relate it to $d^2f_{x}$ which is a bilinear map. So to do this I would first have to do a composition of $x\mapsto \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n)$ with a som function $\phi:f\in\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n)\mapsto f(u)\in \mathbb{R}^n$. I suppose that the problem is how to show explicitly that $d^2f$appears which requires the differentiation of a differentfunction